# How to collapse a heading/parent point in orgmode while generating a website?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, web

I have a heading "Project" in my generated website which looks something like this:

```
* Projects  
- Project A: Intro about the project 
    - In detail about Project A (has a couple of paragraphs)
- Project B: Intro about the project 
    - In detail about Project B (has a couple of paragraphs and images)
```

So, I want it to collapse to just show

```
* Projects  
- Project A: Intro about the project 
- Project B: Intro about the project
```

And on clicking Project A, it should show the details of Project A and so on.

Is there a way of doing it using Emacs to generate the website?

Comment: You need Javascript to do this kind of thing. Emacs can only go so far.

Comment: Although, I guess [org-info-js](https://orgmode.org/manual/JavaScript-support.html) its [plain view mode](https://orgmode.org/worg/code/org-info-js/#terms) is probably not an acceptable alternative (solution) here, I still would like to mention it (to be sure).